# Line height for list items affecting readability

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

This is a pretty minor issue:

I was browsing Writers site and noticed the line-height for list items is inconsistent with other sites (like SO). It is 16px instead of 18px. I noticed because I was having difficulty reading [this answer](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/1781/creating-the-plot#answer-1786). This may affect other sites as well.

**Proposed resolution** is to increase the line-height to aid readability. It may be advantageous to add a small bottom margin as well, but not strictly necessary.

The line height is set in *all.css*, line: *136*

Comment: You can add an additional line break after each list item. This creates `li > p`s instead of just `li`, so there is now a small margin under each `li` element from the `p` elements

Answer (score 3):

I have increased the line-height and added a margin-bottom to LIs. They now use em instead of px. They shouldn't have been px to begin with. Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

The line height shouldn't be in pixels at all!
It should be a ratio, eg: `line-height: 1.5;`, so that when users scale the font up to increase the dismal readability, the line spacing doesn't get even worse. (It also make it easier to maintain or modify the CSS.)

Zillions of years of readability and typography studies show that the ratio should be at least 1.5.

This ratio is also supported by web-readability studies.  See [*Typographic Design Patterns and Best Practices*](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/20/typographic-design-survey-best-practices-from-the-best-blogs/), for example.