# Line height on badge descriptions should be increased

Tags: bug, badges, design

The line-height for the badge descriptions is too low. At the moment, it's set at `line-height: 1`, which looks pretty bad - especially with the "Curious", "Inquisitive", and "Socratic" badges, where the lines sort of flow together:

[image: The line height of badge descriptions]

As discussed in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82852/201907) by Awesome Poodles, the line height should be set at `line-height: 1.5` at the minimum for readability.

Comment: I'll see your 1.5 and meet you in the middle at 1.25

Comment: @lostsock _*folds*_